# What is the common way to cast non-nullable or return default(Type)

Tags: c#, syntax, casting

Working with all the dictionaries within ASP.NET MVC (like RouteData, DataTokens etc), I often find myself wanting to do stuff like:

```
bool isLolCat = routeData["isLolcat"] as bool
```

that would return the casted value, or default (false in this case) when the value is null.

Is there any short, readable, simple way to do this, or am I better off writing a helper extension method?

An extension method would something like this.

```
bool isLolCat = routeData["isLolcat"].TryCast<bool>();
```

- I rather don't want to reinvent the wheel with custom syntax if there is a common way to do this.
- I don't want to litter my code with a few lines, when I just to try to get a bool out of a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you like any of these:

```
(routeData["isLolcat"] as bool?).GetValueOrDefault()
(routeData["isLolcat"] as bool?).GetValueOrDefault(false)
(routeData["isLolcat"] as bool?) ?? false
```

If not you'll have to write a helper. I actually recommend using a helper because the code that I posted kind of obfuscates what you mean. I'd rather see this:

```
routeData.GetOrDefault<bool>("isLolcat")
```

Because this documents in writing what you intend.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any short, readable, simple way to do this, or am I better off writing a helper extension method?

I'd say you would be better writing your own extension because you can make your intentions clear

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static T CastOrDefault<T>(this object obj)
    {
        return obj is T ? (T)obj : default(T);           
    }
}
...
bool isLolCat = RouteData["isLolCat"].CastOrDefault<bool>();
```

Suggestion - If you wanted to keep it short, you could call it something like `As<T>`

```
bool isLolCat = RouteData["isLolCat"].As<bool>();
string str = RouteData["isLolCat"].As<string>(); // null
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a most common way, all casting / conversion operations have their own idiosyncrasies.

For example, `Convert.ToBool` can accept strings to convert, do you want this to convert, or should this fail?

`x as bool` will give you null if it's not of type `bool`.

I think it would be best to write an extension method for `RouteData`.

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this RouteData routeData, string field)
{
    var value = routeData[field];

    if (value is T)
    {
        return (T)value;
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

This way you're operating on the `RouteData` class and not potentially null values.

Usage:

```
var isLolCat = routeData.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("IsLolCat");
```